# How to specify ssh-config for TLD-less domains?

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I’m trying to specify configuration for commands of the form `ssh foo` or `ssh bar`; where foo and bar are actually `foo.xyz.org` and `bar.xyz.org` but `xyz.org` is supplied by my VPN search domain.

I’ve looked through the man page but I cannot figure out a way of doing this.

Domain canonicalization seems to come close to accomplishing what I need, provided I know xyz.org beforehand.

```
Host *
    CanonicalDomains xyz.org
    CanonicalizeHostname yes
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but won't this work (in `~/.ssh/config`):

```
CanonicalDomains xyz.org
Match canonical final host *.xyz.org
  User root
```

?

Comment: This works, but the idea is that I don’t want this to hold for *only* xyz.org domains — but instead any TLD-less host (resolution works via DHCP-set search domain).

Answer (score 0):

On your ~/.ssh/config, you can create a specific config per host, eg

```
   Host f1
   User xrisk
   Hostname foo
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519-test
```

You can then ssh to it using its shortname: `ssh s1`

Comment: This is not a good solution, I have hundreds of hosts which are all resolved by our internal DNS.

Comment: Did you know that if domain .xyz.org is supplied by your resolver and your local /etc/resolv.conf contains the line ```search xyz.org```, then that's all you need. You can just do ```ssh f1```. Or if that is even too long to type, you can even add that to your aliases: ```alias f1="ssh f1"``` so all you need to type is: ```f1```

Comment: Yes I do have a search domain set. I can already type `ssh f1` and it works. The point is that I want to specify ssh config rules for all domains resolved that way (without hard coding the search domain)! For example `User root`.